# Compiling againts especific version of armhf g++

Tags: c++, linux, qt, gcc

I'm doing a crossbuild of a QT app from a Debian (Stretch) PC to a Debian (Jessie) BeagleBone Black, and when I executed this, I got the message

```
/home/bbuser/totemguard/totemguard: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.22' not found (required by /home/bbuser/totemguard/totemguard)
```

I saw that the armhf g++ version was 6.1 so I install the 4.9.2-10 (the same that I had on the BeagleBone Black) and recompiled my code, with similar result (different GLIBXX version):

```
/home/bbuser/totemguard/totemguard: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /home/bbuser/totemguard/totemguard)
```

Reading the [ABI Policy and Guidelines](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html), the G++ version for GLIBCXX_3.4.21 is 5.1.0:

> GCC 4.9.0: GLIBCXX_3.4.20, CXXABI_1.3.8
>
> GCC 5.1.0: GLIBCXX_3.4.21, CXXABI_1.3.9
>
> GCC 6.1.0: GLIBCXX_3.4.22, CXXABI_1.3.10

But I never had the 5.1 version installed on my host PC or BeagleBone Black board.

Listing the /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ directory we can see that there are only the GCC 4.9.0 and GCC 6.1.0 libstdc++ version:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      19 ago  3 15:53 libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.22
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  658064 dic 27  2014 libstdc++.so.6.0.20
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1019632 ago  3 15:53 libstdc++.so.6.0.22
```

This problem begin after a distro-upgrade from jessie to stretch, and I can't upgrade the beaglebone black gcc version.

What can I do?

EDIT 1:
On a test board (BeagleBone Black) I added the stretch repository and did this:

```
bbuser@beaglebone:~/totemguard$ sudo apt-cache policy libstdc++6
libstdc++6:
    Installed: 4.9.2-10
    Candidate: 6.1.1-11
    Version table:
        6.1.1-11 0
            500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch/main armhf Packages
    *** 4.9.2-10 0
    500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main armhf Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
bbuser@beaglebone:~/totemguard$ sudo apt-get install libstdc++6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
    gcc-6-base
The following NEW packages will be installed:
    gcc-6-base
The following packages will be upgraded:
    libstdc++6
1 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 726 not upgraded.
Need to get 517 kB of archives.
...
```

And the application ran fine (not 100% tested, but give no errors). Still this is a test board and I cant do the same on a production board.

Answer (score 0):

solution 1) use -static (full libraries) or compile-in only libstdc++ as static to the binary

solution 2) distribute the appropriate libstdc++ version with the binary (possibly using LD_PRELOAD)

solution 3) use exactly the same g++ libstdc++ version for crosscompiling (at least matching)

usually better is to use solution 1) - you will have no problems across distros upgrade

Comment: I tried the "solution 3", matching the g++ and gcc version (this came with libstdc++ 3.4.20, but it still link to 3.4.21. There is my problem. I will try the solution 1 in a few days. Thanks.

Comment: this is because the new library is still present in cross-compiling environment. You can just remove it or pass implicitly particular one when compiling: gcc my_prog.cpp /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.xx.x -lother_libraries